# Upgrade MySQL to 5.6 on ec2

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

I just started using aws. I had a database on namecheap and when I tried to migrate it on EC2
instance Amazon Linux AMI 2016.03.0 (HVM), I got an error.
On further examining the error, I noticed that, the mysql version is not correct(need to upgrade it in order to import the database).

The error which am getting :

```
"#1293 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause"
```

Now, my current mysql version is (I copied it from phpmyadmin) :`Server version: 5.5.46 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)` and I need to upgrade it to 5.6

I tried

```
sudo yum update mysql-server
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
963 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Package(s) mysql-server available, but not installed.
No packages marked for update
```

I also tried to disable the priority plugin using [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/312472/what-does-that-mean-packages-excluded-due-to-repository-priority-protections), but it's still not working.

Can someone please tell me how to upgrade it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Uninstall your current MySQL version, and then run:

```
sudo yum install mysql56-server
```

Comment: Will I loose my existing db? and the user's which I created over there? Thanks.

Comment: I deleted the mysql and now am not able to install it using the above command. Check the link, http://pastebin.com/YTCnGjpH

Comment: Sorry, the correct command is: `sudo yum install mysql56-server`. I'll edit my answer to reflect that also.

Comment: Still giving an error. `Error: perl-DBD-MySQL56 conflicts with perl-DBD-MySQL55-4.023-5.23.amzn1.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest`

Comment: You'll have to uninstall any MySQL55 packages it complains about. Just read the error messages.

Comment: Sorry to keep bugging you but i removed `sudo yum remove perl-DBD-MySQL55` and after that I installed mysql56, but when am trrying to start the service, it's showing failed. Any input?

Comment: Log file didn't show anything. It just won't work. But yeah, your command is the one which I was missing. Thanks.

Comment: Is this going to remove the data?

Comment: using this command, old user, password and database stay as it is ? or need to generate again?

Answer (score 9):

try to remove the mysql libs also :

`yum remove mysql55-libs`

Answer (score 2):

Use the following commands:

```
yum remove mysql55-server
yum install mysql56-server
/etc/init.d/mysqld start
mysql_upgrade
```

To upgrade from 5.6 to 5.7 (to have JSON field type for example):

```
yum remove mysql56-server
yum install mysql57-server
/etc/init.d/mysqld start
mysql_upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this with below commands

```
sudo yum remove mysql55-server
sudo yum install mysql56-server
sudo service mysqld start
```

Happy coding :-)